# Broadcast receiver listening to phone state changes

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I currently have an alarm manager and a broadcast receiver to send notifications at a certain time each day. Currently, each time a phone call is made the notifications activate and I beleive this is from the broadcast receiver listening to the changes in phone state, but I have no idea how to stop it listening to a change in phone state. Here is my code below:

```
public class Alarm_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {




if (return_cow_id.isEmpty()){
}else{
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, 
        new Intent(context, Cows_On_Heat.class), 0);

   NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Cow/s due back on heat today: ")
        .setContentText(return_cow_id);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}

if (calve_cow_id.isEmpty()){


   }else{



    PendingIntent contentIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, 
            new Intent(context, Cows_Calving.class), 0);

   NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder1 =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Cow/s due to calve in 7 days: ")
            .setContentText(calve_cow_id);
    mBuilder1.setContentIntent(contentIntent1);
    mBuilder1.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder1.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager1 =
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager1.notify(2, mBuilder1.build());
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

see [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130519/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html)

use the method in that tutorial to listen for the phone state and use boolean variable in the  PhoneStateListener subclass to control your return_cow_id.isEmpty() & calve_cow_id.isEmpty() if conditions, like so:

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String incomingNumber){
        switch(state){
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.d("DEBUG", "IDLE");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Log.d("DEBUG", "OFFHOOK");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                Log.d("DEBUG", "RINGING");
                break;
        }
        phone_state_changed = true; //here is your phone state controller variable 
    } 
}
```

then your receiver should look like this :

```
if (return_cow_id.isEmpty()){
}else{
    if (!phone_state_changed){
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, 
        new Intent(context, Cows_On_Heat.class), 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Cow/s due back on heat today: ")
            .setContentText(return_cow_id);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        phone_state_changed = false; //now it will work as a toggler
    }
}
if (calve_cow_id.isEmpty()){
}else{
    if(!phone_state_changed){
        PendingIntent contentIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, 
            new Intent(context, Cows_Calving.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder1 =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Cow/s due to calve in 7 days: ")
            .setContentText(calve_cow_id);
        mBuilder1.setContentIntent(contentIntent1);
        mBuilder1.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder1.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager1 =
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager1.notify(2, mBuilder1.build());
        phone_state_changed = false; //now it will work as a toggler
    }
}
}
```

hope I helped, if I did please consider dropping an accepted answer if not then don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I found the problem. I had the action defined as a phone state change. So what I did was create a custom intent and action